# Apache htaccess rewrite to HHVM

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, hhvm

I want the Hip Hop Virtual Machine run php code for only one specific website. All other websites and images will still be served by Apache. I have installed HHVM and it's running on port 88.

I guess I need to add a rewrite rule to .htaccess of that website to redirect requests for .php files to port 88. Is this the right solution? If so, what should I add?

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to reverse proxy instead. If you have access to the vhost/server config files, you can add lines like this:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*)\.php$ http://127.0.0.1:88/$1.php
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:88/
```

Or if you have mod_proxy turned on, you can do this in the htaccess file using the `P` flag:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ http://127.0.0.1:88/$1.php [L,P]
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:88/
```

Answer (score 3):

I've found a solution by setting the sourceroot to the specific website, which is based on the SLIM/PHP framework. It happened to serve no images, so no need to filter on that. Here is the config for HHVM:

```
Server {
  Port = 88
  SourceRoot = /var/www/<specific-folder>
  DefaultDocument = index.php
}

VirtualHost {
  www {
    Pattern = .*
    ServerVariables {
        PHP_SELF = /index.php
        SCRIPT_NAME = /index.php
    }
    RewriteRules {
      index {
        pattern = ^(.*)$
        to = index.php/$1
        qsa = true
      }
    }
  }
}
```